# How to register Ansible actions in Windows Event Log?

Tags: windows, logging, ansible, windows-event-log

Ansible: 2.9
Windows: W2k16 Server

I'm searching for a method to register (log) Ansible actions in remote Windows host.

For example, when I work with `win_command` module for `echo test` command, I can't find lines referring to this action in Windows Event Log.

How can I make the ansible actions show up in the Windows Event log?

Comment: What are the specific lines you are expecting, and what lines are produced?

Comment: \_ In to "Windows Events" I like found "Ansible_user launch command: echo test" with stdout: "The result command".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question that you like to [Register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) and log [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html) from [`win_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_command_module.html#return-values) in Windows Event Log.

You could use [`win_eventlog_entry` – Write entries to Windows event logs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_eventlog_entry_module.html) and something like

```yaml
- name: Save the result of 'whoami' in 'result'
  ansible.windows.win_command: whoami
  register: result

- name: Write 'result.stdout' to Windows Event Log
  community.windows.win_eventlog_entry:
    log: Result of win_command
    source: Ansible module win_command
    event_id: 1234
    message: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```